# Spring Batch - Custom Line Mapper to store csv content line by line in a column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working with Spring Batch and am new to it. The idea is to read a CSV file line by line and write it to a database. Each line should be stored in a single column called line_content. There are other fields - file_name, execution_id

The tutorials I have gone through delimit based on a separator and map to the domain object. My understanding is that:

FlatFileItemReader is configured to read from a CSV file.
LineMapper defines how each line is mapped to a domain object.
DelimitedLineTokenizer specifies the delimiter ("," in this case).
BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper is used to map fields to a domain object.

How to create a custom line mapper that allows the mapping to the domain object? Also, what is the best way to approach this?

Already tried the following

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<MyDomainObject> itemReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MyDomainObject>()
        .name("itemReader")
        .resource(new FileSystemResource("data.csv"))
        .names(new String[] {"file_name", "line_content", "execution_id"})
        .lineMapper(lineMapper())
        .build();
}

@Bean
public LineMapper<MyDomainObject> lineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<MyDomainObject> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(null);
    lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"file_name", "line_content", "execution_id"});
    
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<MyDomainObject>() {{
        setTargetType(MyDomainObject.class);
    });
    
    return lineMapper;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the requirement is to store the entire line as text in the "line_content" column.

```
public class CustomLineMapper implements LineMapper<MyDomainObject> {
    @Override
    public MyDomainObject mapLine(String line, int lineNumber) throws Exception {
        MyDomainObject domainObject = new MyDomainObject();
        domainObject.setLineContent(line);
        return domainObject;
    }
}

@Bean
public LineMapper<MyDomainObject> lineMapper() {
    return new CustomLineMapper();
}


@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<MyDomainObject> itemReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<MyDomainObject>()
        .name("itemReader")
        .resource(new FileSystemResource("data.csv"))
        .lineMapper(lineMapper())
        .build();
}
```

Comment: If the file name is passed as a job parameter, then the mapper could be made step scoped to inject the file name from parameters at runtime. Same thing for the execution id.

Comment: True. Thanks for the suggestion